# How to write a makefile for changing paths in another set of makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have 7 c++ makefiles they contain **LFLAGS=" some path"**,

I want to write one makefile for all makefile modify LFLAGS path with a single shot.

my make files extension is **filename.mak**

Is there any way...

Comment: Did you try to `export` `LFLAGS` as a global variable?

Comment: @paul, I am trying to change the LFLAGS  path value in several make files through a separate makefile in single attempt, I can define one makefile for  LFLAGS  path, defined this same path apply to all make files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the other makefiles with

```
make LPATH="/home/mynicedir" target
```

from your top level makefile. $(LPATH) refers then to "/home/mynicedir".

This tutorial shows it in detail :

http://aggregate.org/rfisher/Tutorials/Make/make6.html

Comment: ,I need to change all LFLAGS path at a time in single make file, i will define LFLAGS  path in one makefile , this path will automatically change in my all make files, whenever I want path changes then i change in one my make file If I execute that make file all file paths automatically change for me.. I don't want $(LFLAGS ) in my all make files...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can include that makefile which set the `LFLAFS`inside the other makefiles:

```
include  filename.mak
```